# How to change the function signature

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner to Haskell and is now trying to develop a postfix calculator.
Below is my code so far:

```
calcK :: String -> String
calcK =  show calc

calc :: String -> [Double]
calc = foldl interprete [] . words

interprete s x
  | x `elem` ["+","-","*","/","^"] = operate x s
  | x `elem` ["inc","dec","sqrt","sin","cos","inv"] =  operate2 x s
  | x `elem` ["+all"] =  [sum s]
  | x `elem` ["*all"] =  [product s]
  | otherwise = read x:s
  where
    operate op (x:y:s) = case op of
      "+" -> x + y:s
      "-" -> y - x:s
      "*" -> x * y:s
      "/" -> y / x:s
      "^" -> y ** x:s
    operate2 op (x:s) = case op of
      "inc" ->1 + x:s
      "dec" -> (-1) + x:s
      "sqrt" -> sqrt x:s
      "sin" -> sin x:s
      "cos" -> cos x:s
      "inv" -> 1 / x:s
```

It works just for basic operations. However, I came to realize that I need to have the signature defined as

```
   String -> String
```

not `String -> [Double]`. So the calculation result for `"1 2 +"` should be

```
  "[3.0]"
```

instead of

```
   [3.0]
```

As you can see, I've tried to do a `show` at the top but it does not seem to be working. I've tried adding `show` to other places of the code but still no luck.

Would be grateful if experts could offer some advice on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only problem is that you are trying to show the `calc` function, not its *result*.

```
calcK :: String -> String
calcK = show . calc
```

You want to compose `show` and `calc`, letting `calc` produce a `[Double]` which is then passed to `show`.

Comment: Especially for beginners, I think it’s worth noting that this is the same as `calcK x = show (calc x)`.

Comment: Right, I didn’t see that.